# PHP - form action calling itself, how to display everything in 1 page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two .php files as such:

test1.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test2.php" method="post">
        Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

test2.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Display Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
    $user_number = $_POST["userNumber"];
    echo "You have chosen $user_number";    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know how can I get it all to display on a single page, i.e. on the test1.php, without having to have two files.

Comment: ... Seems the consensus is to use `isset` lol

Comment: it's not adviced to have it on one page because you will post the same value on refresh.

Comment: @SamotnyPocitac Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: to clear the post values is to use redirect. For example, process file will be test2.php and redirecting back to test1.php. However this applies when you are entering values into a database.

Comment: why not clear out the values with an empty declaration at the beginning of the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `test1.php` will need to look like this

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test1.php" method="post">
        Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST["userNumber"])) { 
        $user_number = $_POST["userNumber"];
        echo "You have chosen $user_number";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty easy way of doing it. By using the if(isset($_POST[...)), can I do the same for multiple forms?

Answer (score 7):

Check if `$_POST["userNumber"]` [isset](http://php.net/isset), and echo the form if it's not.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST["userNumber"]){
            echo "You have chosen ".$_POST["userNumber"];
        }else{
            echo '<form action="test1.php" method="post">';
            echo 'Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>';
            echo '<input type="submit">';
            echo '</form>';
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to remove the action="test2.php" section and combine both pages into one just like the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['userNumber'])){
        $user_number = $_POST['userNumber'];
        echo "You have chosen $user_number";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple actually:

```
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php   
        if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['userNumber'])) {
            $user_number = $_POST["userNumber"];
            echo "You have chosen $user_number";    
        }
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php   
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { 
    $user_number = $_POST["userNumber"];
    echo "You have chosen $user_number";    
    }
else {
?>
<form method="post">
    Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitted">
</form>
<?php
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

set the variables up before the form as placeholders and check for isset

```
<?php
$user_number = '';
if(isset($_POST["userNumber"])) { 
    $user_number = $_POST["userNumber"];
}
?>

<form action="test2.php" method="post">
    Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

<p>You have chosen: <?php echo $user_number ?></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `isset()` for submit button, note that i added `name="submit"` to your button since it was missing

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])
{
    $user_number = $_POST["userNumber"];
    echo "You have chosen $user_number";    
} else {
?>
    <form action="test2.php" method="post">
        Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is fully tested and allows you to revise the value after submission.  You still have to worry about cross-site scripting attacks, etc...  but that is outside of the scope of the question.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $user_number = '';
    if (isset($_POST['userNumber'])) {
        $user_number=$_POST['userNumber'];
    ?>
    <p>You have chosen <?php echo $user_number ?></p>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
    Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber" value="<?php echo $user_number ?>"><br>
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Sample
>
> ```
> <form action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="post">
>     Please enter a number <input type="number" name="userNumber"><br>
>     <input type="submit">
> </form>
>  </body> </html>
> ```

Comment: <?php $_PHP_SELF ?>