# PHP mail() was converting html tags in the $msg and now isn't?

Tags: php, email

In php file:

```
 mail("person@comcast.net", "Member provided info through website",
 $msg);
```

the $msg posts to website with html uncoded just fine.  In the email it's plain text.

At top of php file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>EmailMemberInfo.php</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
```

Here's what shows in email (and is in the $msg variable):

```
<b>Here's a member's info!<br><br> </b>fip ,
```

And on website:`

```
**Here's a member's info!**
  fip , sharon ,
```

(I've truncated the rest...)

I'm running on my website host, and it's their php that's running.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!!

=============================================

SOLVED -- see the help received below!

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

in the html body to set the $header variable.  The \r\n is a needed code to concatenate the lines.

Then putting that header variable into the mail() function in the 4th argument.

It can be concatenated with a "from email" if desired for that 4th argument.  (see w3's site on mail() function: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp )

And that's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the headers in the fourth argument in the `mail()` function so the email knows to render the HTML:

```
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Just wondering (I know you're probably new here), but why don't you accept answers on any of your questions? It's a courtesy to do so on this site if someone has helped you solve your problem and promotes a better community.

Comment: What does "accept answers" mean?  I arrow up on answers.  I've only asked one other, so nothing is a habit yet.  I'd read stack rules over a year ago but used only a short while, so probably not remembering everything in the set up.  Tonight, I was working on the problem.  When done at some point later in the evening I'd take a break, and come back to look for arrows and things to click...  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry for sounding so presumptuous. To accept an answer, you click on the checkmark below the answers on your question, and it helps for people who are also facing the same problem as you. Again sorry

Comment: Not presumptuous.  I've very glad you asked!!  How would I know if someone didn't point it out?  I see the check mark.  Since it turns color with the first arrow click, I'd assumed it was part of that.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `htmlentities()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

```
# cat test2.php
<?php
echo htmlentities('Loïc')."\n";

# php test2.php
Lo&iuml;c
```

Comment: Thanks.  It didn't object to string htmlentities ( string $msg); but that didn't code it.

Comment: I was looking to email (not echo) and have it interpret the html so it bold's bold etc.  I haven't heard of this function before.  I got the problem working with headers, but I'll mark this concept since I'm sure it will come in handy...  Maybe it was using it a little differently than I was that would work.  The string line I mention in cmt above actually did object the next time I ran it.  Thanks for the info!!

Answer (score 1):

You should use special headers so your Email client can know that it should treat the string as HTML.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
email($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Where do I put the headers?  They don't go straight into the <head> ...</head> area.  Sorry for sounding like such a dup on this.

Comment: Just use the function `mail`. `mail("person@hotmail.com","Subject","Message",$headers);`

Comment: I've got it!  Thanks!  I put the headers in as a variable setting at the beginning, and then included the variable as the 4th argument to the mail function...   and the email is now showing html formatted text.

Comment: As  a quick add on question - when I run the input form that calls this php, the php opens a new tab, even if the only output is that mail function... and no echos or prints.  Is there a setting that turns that off?  I can ask in a new question, but if it's quick and you know, that will finish up this php for me finally for tonight!

Comment: I think you are looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209036/php-form-action-calling-itself-how-to-display-everything-in-1-page

Comment: Thank you very much!  That's in the family.  Meanwhile I decide to use that (pointless screen) as the place for a welcome message and button to continue.  Just need to look up how to get ""'s in commands into echo quoted text to display... and that will look nice.  In the long run maybe I'll do what that link suggests... and set on code on first pass, check for it on 2nd pass with action to itself, to route through refreshing with a welcome message on the same tab.  Thanks again for your help -- it's great!